# How to replace back-slash with nothing in Bash script

Tags: bash, sh

In a bash script, I would like to get the current date in the format of `YYYY\mm\dd`.

Then I want to remove the back slash `\` and store the result in a variable, `FOO`.

My code is

```
FOO=$($(date +'%Y\%m\%d')//\\/)
echo "$FOO"
```

The literal words for `//\\/` are

1. `//` replace for every
2. `\\` back slash
3. `/`  with
4. nothing

However, I got the error

```
2019\12\04/\/: No such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Er, just `$(date +'%Y%m%d')`?

Comment: @Shawn hahaha. Too much

Comment: Who uses backslashes for dates in the first place?

Comment: Anyways, sounds like you're expecting parameter expansion rules to apply to `$()` command substitution?

Comment: @chepner in the first place, I still use forwarding-slash for date format. I just want to play around :-D

Comment: @Shawn yes, I just want to try other ways to work with `$` in Bash. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59178955/5657159, I got what I want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter expansions don't nest; you need to do them as separate steps.

```
foo=$(date +'%Y\%m\%d')
foo=${foo//'\'/}
echo "$foo"
```

Note the use of lower-case variable names -- this is per [POSIX-defined convention](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), which specifies all-uppercase names as used for variables meaningful to the shell or operating system, and reserves other names for application use.

Answer (score 2):

The script has two nested '$(' construct. One should do the work. The second one should be `${}` to remove the unwanted `\`

```
YMD=$(date +'%Y\%m\%d')
FOO=${YMD//\\/}
echo "$FOO"
```

The error message is triggered when the formatted date is forced as a command by the outside '$('. Also note that `${}` can not be nested unlike `$()`, they REQUIRE a variable name.

Side question - why add `\`, when you do not need it ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your question as well. Honestly, I just play around with bash shell and particular with parameter expansion, so I added not-really-needed-stupid stuff to test it :-)

Comment: @trdngy, just learning bash by playing around is dangerous -- there are lots of pitfalls, and generally, things that *look* like they work until the data is interesting enough. At minimum, have a look through [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Answer (score 2):

The `${var//\\/}` uses `{` `}` braces and it is a [variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), it needs a variable to expand.

You can:

```
FOO=$(date +'%Y\%m\%d')
FOO=${FOO//\\/}
```